# SC_METHOD Exception

Tags: systemc

I'm trying to use a SC_METHOD in my simulation. Here is the code:

```
gcrypt::gcrypt(sc_module_name name): 
    gcrypt_base(name)
{
    SC_METHOD(on_clock_update);
    sensitive << clock;
    dont_initialize();
};

void gcrypt::on_clock_update()
 {
     if (clock.read() == 0)
     {
         SC_REPORT_WARNING(name(), "Invalid clock port value of 0");
         _ns_per_cycle = 0;
         return;
     }
     _ns_per_cycle = 1e9 / clock.read();
 }
```

The gcrypt_base constructor is:

```
gcrypt_base::gcrypt_base(sc_module_name name) :
    sc_module(name),
    ...
{
    ...
}
```

I get this exception thrown by SC_METHOD:

> Exception thrown at 0x6FB78281 (vcruntime140d.dll) in
>   SystemCModuleTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x115348EF.

I saw the __vfptr value was "Unable to read memory".

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you haven't specified the [`/vmg` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/cpp/build/reference/vmb-vmg-representation-method) while compiling your code. The `/vmg` option is required because of the way SystemC implements method processes.